# Do you get a new chemical compound if you mix sodium hydroxide and water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, water

Me and dad started fighting over this a couple of days ago and wagered on this.

He said mixing these two gives a chemical compound, I said that it doesn't.

Comment: Is *what* a chemical compound? The mixture?

Comment: Is it a chem compound the mixture of water and sodium hydroxyde.

Comment: Then you are right. NaOH is a compound, so is H2O, but their mixture isn't.

Comment: We need the **exact** sentence for your bet, because it is more tricky than you (and your father) think.

Comment: My dad said:
"In my work we combine NaOH and a chemical compound occurs" 
Me:
"It is not a chemical fusion/compound, because there is no new compound being created, it's just a mix"

Comment: How much was the wager?

Comment: Sodium  hydroxide dissociates into sodium cation($\ce{Na+}$) and hydroxide anion ($\ce{OH-}$) in aqueous medium.

Comment: We cannot say that it is forming a compound or a mixture clearly. Actually what happens is that NaOH just breaks down into Na and OH when it added to water and the mixture posses the properties of Na, OH and water, so u may say that if NaOH is added to water then a mixture of Na, OH and water is formed.

Answer (score 1):

According to Oxford's dictionary of chemistry "A compound is a mixture of two or more elements in a fixed ratio".
So if $\ce{NaOH}$ (in solid state) is added to water, it just dissociates into its constituent ions that are $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$. You can add any ratios of two until you cannot add any more.

Comment: He doesn't want to admit I am right. When I showed him what you said he just clicked the power button on my laptop.

Comment: did he prove to you that it is a "compound"

Comment: Another take could be this: Assuming it is a chemical compound, it must mixture possess the characteristics a chemical compound must have, then show that that mixture of water does not have those properties, one of them being the fixed ratio thing, and if this is the case, our assumption is wrong that is mixture of water and sodium hydroxide is not a chemical compound.

Comment: @Alek It may be futile to argue with a brick wall...

Answer (score 1):

What exactly counts as a compound is not exactly clear cut, and probably not a really useful distinction a lot of the time. It's fair to say that a solution of NaOH in water is not a new compound, though.

If you start with pure crystals of NaOH however, adding water can create new compounds: NaOH.1H2O and NaOH.4H2O (the tetrahydrate appears to be polymorphic, so there's another can of worms there).